# postgrey whitelist recipients not working

Tags: debian, greylisting, postgrey

I have installed postgrey and it works fine but I want to exclude some email accounts. So as manual says I added account name into whitelist_recipients then restarted postrgey, postfix but as You can see in log - new mail are still greylisted for excluded user. What did I missed?

/etc/postgrey/whitelist_recipients

```
1 # postgrey whitelist for mail recipients
2 # --------------------------------------
3 # put this file in /etc/postgrey or specify its path
4 # with --whitelist-recipients=xxx
5 
6 postmaster@
7 abuse@
8 automat@
10 l.koko@
```

-
postfix log:

```
   Jun 24 11:13:38 server postgrey[13949]: action=greylist, reason=new, client_name=forfree.os.pl, client_address=62.210.151.99, sender=l.bubu@adresik.com, recipient=l.koko@example.com.pl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the service restart did not worked.
So I had to kill the postgrey process manually and then start the service.
Now it works  like a charm.